# Deleting certain text from textarea with large amounts of data

Tags: javascript, html

I made a basic XML formatter using HTML and Javascript. I would like to add a delete function to this.  Basically, I would like to be able to delete an entry, but without clearing or marring any other data.

```
<contact
<!--John Doe-->
 first_name="John"
 last_name="Doe"
 contact_type="sip"
 account_id="104"
 subscribe_to="sip:104@10.10.1.24"
 has_voicemail="1"
 can_monitor="1"
>
<numbers>
 <number dial="1064" dial_prefix="" label="Extension" />
 <number dial="555-0123" dial_prefix="718" label="Work Line" primary="1" />
```

The way I was thinking was to find the contact tag containing John Doe and deleting from `<contact` to `</numbers>`

Could `indexOf() be used to delete this group by containing certain information.

**For context:** I added a demo to plunkr. This takes form data and exports it to a textarea

http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/b9QKZ7KZP0IlcyeCTTc9/

Comment: What *other data* should not be affected?

Comment: Other contacts in the list.  So, if I wanted to delete John Doe, but not Jane.

Comment: i don't see a </numbers>...

Comment: Using only string operations will fail on more complex XML (just image a CDATA section that contains the text `<numbers>` that you want to look for as ending delimiter). I would suggest parsing it into an XML document, so that you can remove _nodes_ from it using regular DOM methods, and then converting it back to text for displaying.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might try a other way.

1. Create some Javascript Objects to hold the data.
2. Present objects to that textarea.
3. When you add/remove a data, operate the objects first, then re-present.

Code looks like

```
//Contact list.
var contacts = [];

// Contact class.
function Contact() {
    ...
    this.name = "";
    this.numbers = [];// numbers
    ...
}

Contact.prototype.toString = function(){
    return "<contact name=\"" + this.name + ...;
};

// Add new Contact
function addContact(params) {

    var contact = new Contact();
    // set properties
    // contact.name = name;
    contacts.push(contact);
    showContacts();
}

// Add new Contact
function deleteContact(name) {

    for (var i = contacts.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (contacts[i].name == name) {
            contacts.splice(i, 1);
            return;
        }
    }
}

// present contacts
function showContacts(){
    var text = "";
    for(var c in contacts){
        text += c.toString();
    }
    textarea.value = text;
}

// other functions like addNumber etc.
```

Code will become a little complicate, but more clear and flexible.